# How can I edit a pdf on the web (mysql database and php). Pdf should be edited online and the client is not required to have a pdf editor

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I need an online pdf editor so that when I pull the pdf name using php It automatically opens the pdf in the editor and the user can edit the pdf. By edit I mean to chage text, images,etc.... and I want to know how to link php and mysql to it so that when clicking on the pdf name in the database, the pdf is automatically opened via the online editor.
Any recommendation and guides on how to do this ?

Comment: What kind of 'edit'?

Comment: Change text, add images, delete images etc...

Comment: You can use FPDF to create a PDF in PHP, actually editing a PDF is IMHO impossible. Also check out `jsPDF`.

Comment: I will LINK the pdf editor, the mysql database and the pdf editor using PHP. The file should be opened using the PDFEDITOR

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your full requirement here,

but my suggestion is to store HTML versions of the same, this way its gives the flexibility to edit,

also provide a WYSIWYG editor to edit,

and at the time of download, use an HTML to PDF generator.

Also note, you can store the HTML content to DB, or to files, uploads like Image can also be stored into DB (as binary), S3 or somewhere, but decide all that according to your requirement. ~Happy Coding~

Comment: This (or something very much like it) is what I'd do too